# passing an anonymous function to jQuery, and reference to variable scope

Tags: jquery, scope

I am familiar with this construct in jQuery:

```
$('#some-element').doSomethingJQueryDoes();
```

But I don't understand this construct:

```
$(function(){
    ..
});
```

It appears I am passing an anonymous function to jQuery but I am curious:

- When does this execute?  From the code inside it appears to execute on document.ready
- Is there any way to give this function a NAME so that I can call it outside of events happening, outside of its scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When does this execute? From the code inside it appears to execute on document.ready

That is correct. It has the same effect as [`$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ })`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> Is there any way to give this function a NAME so that I can call it outside of events happening, outside of its scope?

Sure, if you want:

```
var myFunc = function() { /* ... */ };

$(myFunc);
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer